# debugging XAMARIN forms apps doesnt always work - why?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to finish a XAMARIN Forms project for a client and the whole time I've had issues.  The biggest annoyance (really too many to list) is that when trying to debug using the iPhone simulator the debugger fails to hook up.  Is there a trick I'm missing?
My setup: 
I'm working on a Windows 10 workstation with a Mac Mini setup as my build server.  I'm using Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise Edition.  The Mac has the latest XCode and XAMARIN Studio stuff installed.
Everything is up to date

Right now the only 'solution' seems to be to stop the debugger in VS and start over.

Occasionally I have to close VS all together, reboot the mac and start from scratch.

Is there a trick?  A checkbox somewhere that says "make this work like it should"?

Comment: We have the same issue, I think it's a VS bug.

Comment: It just never ends.  I created a test bed project to test out some ideas.  Every time I go to debug, if it does hook up VS locks up and has to be killed.

Answer (score 0):

1) are you in Debug mode on not Release ?

2) can you try on real iOS device ?

3) have you try on Xamarin Studio instead of Visual Studio ?

4) does it work on Android (simulator or real device) ?

5) have you try with a new clean project ? if it works try to remove bin & obj folders

Comment: 1 - In debug mode, 2 - having issues with that (getting help), 3 - Working on a PC not a Mac. 4 - At the moment the app will only target iOS so some of the necessary code for Android (form prerenderer for Azure AD) hasnt been written yet, but previously it was working on my Note8. 5 - same things happen with a clean project.

Comment: Oddly enough - today things are mostly working.  No idea why.  Probably related to sun spot activity.  I'm going to wrap the Mac mini in tin foil to protect it from gamma rays.  That will probably fix it.